# I want to plot a function in 3d in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I have a function, **X**. It has inputs *t* and *d*.

**X** generates a 3x1 array, effectively an *X,Y,Z* tuple representing a point in 3-dimensional space.

I want to generate a plot for all values of *t* and *d*, given that 0 < *t* < 360 and 0 < *d* < 5. (They are not vectors.)

Currently I'm doing:

```
plot3(X(1),X(2),X(3),'.');
grid on
```

Which gives me just the one point in space. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to define the range on which you want to evaluate your function. In order to generate a grid of input values, you can use `meshgrid`.

Comment: Yup, I've defined, the range. My problem is that I don't want to graph the out matrix vs the inputs. I want to graph the different components of the output matrix. Not quite sure how to do that for a given range of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

plot3(X(1),X(2),X(3),'.') is simply plotting the point generated by one pair of values for t and d.

You will want to generate an 3xN matrix for all the values of t and d that you want, perhaps using the linspace function to generate all the values of t and d that you want to plot.

Another option would be to use the ezsurf function as follows:

```
ezsurf('t+d',[0 360 0 5])
```